# SQL Performance using dummy FALSE/TRUE Statements

Tags: sql

First post here and please forgive any of my ignorance or lack of correct terminology. I am a developer however have learnt on the job. I worked up from Helpdesk to BA to Programmer so I have fair size gaps in my knowledge, but I'm a quick and eager learner and have years of experience with the business and it's systems which I like to think this makes up for it.

I have written an SQL search that is built in XSL, i.e. a user enters information on their screen and based on what they enter an SQL is built an executed.

My SQL is something like this.

```
Select a,b,c 
from table
where 
1=0
OR Condition 1
OR Condition 2
OR Condition 3
```

The XSL would add the appropriate condition depending user input.

This was fine however on release to a QA environment (with larger db) the search was dog slow, the Condition fields are indexed and are unique, even a straight forward search for a unique identifier took ages.

It was suggested to me the 1=0 was the problem, I didn't believe this to be true and did a chunk of testing.

It turns out...

```
1=1
AND Condition 1
AND Condition 2
AND Condition 3
```

...runs lighting fast, I ran an 'Explain' on both queries and they had exactly the same score. I'm confused why this works Can anyone shed any light on it? I did ask my colleagues but they didn't seem to know.

Thanks,
Chris

EDIT:
I guess the real question I'm asking is... on an ORACLE DB

```
1=0 OR Condition - takes minutes 

1=1 AND Condition - instant
```

Why?

Comment: Changing the OR to AND is the important factor here. They don't do the same thing. The set of people that either play the violin or play poker is considerably larger than the set of people that both play the violin and play poker for example

Comment: The version with `OR` returns many more rows.  And the version with `AND` can possibly use indexes which the `OR` version probably does not.

Comment: Interesting, why would indexes be disregarded for an OR? I should clarify only one of the statements will be run, the user will search either code1, code2 or code3 not all together so the and/or shouldn't matter for the criteria, the dummy statement is only there to stop the queries failing with nothing is entered(Probably is a better way to do that)...

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and performance tuning is highly vendor specific Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Apologies it's Oracle.

Comment: I guess the real question I'm asking is... 

on an ORACLE DB
1=0 OR Condition - takes minutes
1=1 AND Condition - instant

Why?